# Character to time values whilst omitting today's date

Tags: r

Consider an array of character values named `time`, such that :

```
> head(time)
[1] "00:30:04" "00:30:02" "00:30:04" "00:30:04" "00:30:04" "00:30:04"
```

and :

```
> class(time)
[1] "character"
```

I wish to change these character values into time, or `POSIXlt`, values whilst maintaining the aesthetics of the character array. Currently I am using the following function:

```
> t <- strptime(time, "%H:%M:%S")
```

However the outcome forces the generation of today's date in front of the hours, minutes, and seconds, as follows :

```
> head(t)
[1] "2016-04-16 00:30:04 BST" "2016-04-16 00:30:02 BST" "2016-04-16 00:30:04 BST" "2016-04-16 00:30:04 BST" "2016-04-16 00:30:04 BST" "2016-04-16 00:30:04 BST"
```

How do I make it such that today's date is not also generated in front of the hours, minutes and seconds?

**UPDATE**

I should clarify why I am asking this question.

I wish to plot a simple histogram using ggplot2 and plotly. An alternative mechanism is to use the `chron` package to generate the times. I can do so with the following command :

```
TimeOfDay <- chron(times=time)
```

and the result is as follows :

```
> head(TimeOfDay)
[1] 00:30:04 00:30:02 00:30:04 00:30:04 00:30:04 00:30:04
```

However, when I plot a histogram with using the `chron` generated `TimeOfDay` data I get the following histogram :

```
plot_ly(x = TimeOfDay, type = "histogram")
```

[image]

The problem with this histogram is that the x-axis is between the values of 0 and 1 only, and does not truly represent the time that was generated.

Comment: Hmm maybe a [X-Y-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) - what do you want to achieve in the end? For example, using the `data.table` package you could do `as.ITime("01:00:00")`.

Comment: POSXlt is a **date**time class. You want a time class. Look into packages such as package chron.

Comment: @Roland good comment. I have extended the question to reflect why I am having problems with the use of the `chron` package too.

Comment: Use POSIXct and specify the format you want to have displayed to ggplot2.

Comment: @Futh, try `format(as.POSIXct(strptime(time,format = "%H:%M:%S")),"%H:%M:%S")` should do. I am not exactly sure if it is the most elegant, but it's what I use often.

Comment: So, coming back to the X-Y-Problem, the thing you really want is formatting tick labels in plotly, e.g. `x <- as.POSIXct(sample(1:(60*60*24-1), 1000, T), origin="2016-01-01", tz = "GMT");plot_ly(x = x, type = "histogram") %>% layout(xaxis = list(tickformat="%H:%M:%S"))
`?